# Add a table under the description or summary tag in AsyncAPI yaml file

Tags: yaml, asyncapi

I wanted to add a table under the AsyncAPI description or summary tag. But when I added it like swagger, it mixed up and show like a paragraph. I tried | and > symbols also. But didn’t work. Anyone know how to do this in AsyncAPI version 3.0.0 or 2.4.0

```
summary: |
        Test summary description. 
          +------------+
          | H1  | H2   |
          +-----+------+
          | ccc | ccc  |
          +-----+------+
          | ccc | ccc  |
          +-----+------+
```

The above table shows as follows when generated

```
Test summary description. +------------+ | H1 | H2 | +-----+------+ | ccc | ccc | +-----+------+ | ccc | ccc | +-----+------+
```

Comment: Do you mean operation or message summary? Hard to help without details and example AsyncAPI document that you use. The issue might be caused by "trip" functions we use in https://github.com/asyncapi/markdown-template/blob/master/components/Operations.js#L119 but that is just a blind assumption. Please report an issue in the linked repo with more details.

Comment: Ah, yes. That may be the problem. I used “summary”, but the same problem in the “description” also, but we can add list with “-“ in the description. I’ll report an issue. Thank you!